# React form ref issue in Safari while using useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a form in a Modal which is submitted by a button outside the form. I am using **useRef** to create a reference of the form and then submitting it on button click.

```js
const formRef = useRef(null);

const form = (
<Form onSubmit={onSave} ref={formRef}>
.
.
.

</Form>
)

 <CustomModal
  body={form}
  onPrimaryClick={() => {
    formRef.current.requestSubmit();
  }}
/>
```

This code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but throws a TypeError on Safari **I.current.requestSubmit is not a function**
[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and why the code works in other browsers.

Comment: It turns out the method requestSubmit() is not supported in safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit